# What happened to the Millennium Falcon hanging dice prop?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, behind-the-scenes, props

In recent *Star Wars* films and Extended Universe material, a lot has been made of the dice Han Solo originally  had hanging overhead in the Millennium Falcon cockpit.  However, the prop had disappeared by *The Empire Strikes Back*.  Is it known what happened to the original dice prop that was used to dress the cockpit set in *A New Hope*?

Answer (score 13):

Along with many of the items that were custom-made for the original Star Wars films, they were simply "*lost to time*" (e.g. more likely just disposed of at the end of filming).

Note that the props themselves were simply cheap wooden (or plastic) dice, spray-painted gold and given a cheap metal chain and had little or no value in themselves, nor was there any speculation that they would be needed in future for sequels.

> Many props and costumes from those earliest days of filming have been
> lost to time, but the first prop was a simple pair of Earth dice
> painted gold.
>
> <sub><sup>[INSIDE THE LUCASFILM ARCHIVE: HAN SOLO’S DICE](https://www.starwars.com/news/inside-the-lucasfilm-archive-han-solo-dice)</sup></sub>

We do know that they junked the Falcon's cockpit after filming finished. It's reasonable to assume that the dice went into the same skip.

> “In 1977 it wasn’t protocol or typical to save everything from a
> movie.
>
> "Those were just movies, they made it and then everything went away.
> George Lucas was making *A New Hope* with the idea that if it was a
> success he would have two more films he could make.
>
> "And it was a success, but he did save things from that first film
> just in case his gambit worked out which it did. Really, we’re very
> lucky he saved what he did from those films.
>
> "But back then not everything was saved because they were thinking about the next film production; they weren’t thinking about making an archive 40 years later.
>
> “We don’t have an original X-wing from the first film. **We don’t have the original Millennium Falcon, they didn’t build the whole thing but it would be great to have the original cockpit.”**
>
> <sub><sup>[Laela French: director of archives at the Lucas Museum of Narrative Arts - "Star Wars props worth millions DESTROYED - by George Lucas and his own crew"](https://www.mirror.co.uk/tv/tv-news/star-wars-props-worth-millions-9337109)</sup></sub>